# Pick map / deep pick with lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

Is there a way to write this kind of pick/map operation

```
edges = edges.map(([v1, v2]) => [vertices[v1], vertices[v2]]);

// example
const edges = [
  [0, 1],
  [1, 0]
];
const vertices = [
  [0, 0],
  [1, 1]
];   

~~~>

[
  [
    [0, 0],
    [1, 1]
  ],
  [
    [1, 1],
    [0, 0]
  ]
]
```

more elegant, maybe by using lodash?

My so far best solution is this:

```
function pickMap(edges, vertices) {
    return ld.invokeMap(edges, "map", ld.propertyOf(vertices));
}
```

But maybe I'm missing some more basic procedure. Something like

```
edges.map(([v1, v2]) => ld.pick(vertices, [v1, v2]))
```

comes close, but it returns an array of objects with the wrong keys (v1, v2) rather than (0, 1).

Comment: Please add a sample of the input data, and the expected results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `_.at()` to get an array of values using an array of indexes:

```js
const edges = [[0, 1],[1, 0]];
const vertices = [[0, 0],[1, 1]];   

const result = edges.map(v => _.at(vertices, v));

console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-90vH1Z83AJY9DmlWa8WkjkV79yfS2n2Oxhsi2dZbIv0nC4E6m5AbH8Nh156kkM7JePmqD6tcZsfad1ueoaovww==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Great, exactly what I was looking for, thx